# weird python print behaviour

Tags: python, google-app-engine, printing

why this does not print anything:

```
for item in pipe.json["value"]["items"]:
    print item["pubDate"]
```

but this does:

```
for item in pipe.json["value"]["items"]:
   print item["pubDate"] + "\n"
```

p.s. the loop is running inside another loop.

p.p.s. this is running inside google app engine application.i have looked at http response and it is completely empty in the first case.

Comment: Very weird indeed. Are there two newlines after each pubDate?

Comment: @delnan no there aren't any newlines.

Comment: What is the return value of `str(item["pubDate"])`? What is the type returned by `item["pubData"]`? Does it implement `__add__`?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y item["pubDate"] return <type 'unicode'>
str(item["pubDate"]) or unicode(item["pubDate"]) returns ""

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be a problem with buffering, in which case flushing stdout would help.

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using some sort of wsgi framework, or just trying to write pure CGI code (which is a mistake?)

You probably don't want to be using `print` at all here, but rather using your framework's method of adding to the response (for webapp, `self.response.out.write`).  My guess would be that without the extra `\n`, you're writing all of this data to the HTTP headers, and with it you're only losing the first line of your output.

Comment: I would word it more strongly: never, ever use print inside a WSGI app.

Answer (score 1):

On GAE if you want to use print for output you'll have to print an empty string before any printing so that these kind of problems won't happen:

```
print ""
print "something"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, but if item['pubDate'] is a non-string object it might a result of differences between special methods.  Perhaps the `__str__` method returns nothing, while the `__add__` method does something different.